# How to check internet connectivity in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:internet_connection_checker/internet_connection_checker.dart';
/*Error --> Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:internet_connection_checker/internet_connection_checker.dart'.
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist*/
....

void checkingNetwork() async {
      ans = await InternetConnectionChecker().hasConnection;
/*Error -- The method 'InternetConnectionChecker' isn't defined for the type '_WelcomeMessageState'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'InternetConnectionChecker'.*/

    }

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      checkingNetwork();
    }
```

I have this code to check network connectivity but even after adding plugin to pubspec, its giving error. How can I remove this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a package called `internet_connection_checker`, you have to add it to your `pubspec.yaml` file.

Then you can run `flutter pub get` to install the package.

If you have done that, the import line

```
import 'package:internet_connection_checker/internet_connection_checker.dart';
```

should compile successfully and the symbol `InternetConnectionChecker` will be found.

Answer (score 0):

After adding The Package In `pubspec.yaml` Please Do `flutter clean && flutter pub get` command to get the packages , Or You Can Use `connectivity_plus` package . This has listener in it So you Can Track The Internet Connectivity Through The App AllTime